# Show Crystal Report from Dataset Table with Adaptor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, dataset

I am using encryption process and save data in encrypted form. I am using data table to store data for report only with data adopter. I only provide it query and then get my result in it to load.

i want to show decrypted form of data on report. My code is following. Please check and tell me is it possible.

```
Dim report As New WithdrawReport
Dim db As New ADODB.Recordset
db.Open("select * from tbl_withdraw", cn)

report.Load()
report.SetDataSource(db.DataSource)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Please also tell me is it possible to show crystal report only for my datatable. Like i runtime add data in my data table and then generate report from that data table.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your data set and decrypt the data.